# Session Management in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am new to service fabric and unable to know how service fabric performs session management. suppose one node fails, then how the logged-in user session is kept alive by another node which is handling the request?

Answer (score 2):

Service Fabric does not maintain session, it maintain service states.

SF has the concept of [Reliable Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction)  and [Reliable Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections), once you use them on your services, SF will handle the replication across the nodes where your application is running.

SF does not know what a session in your application is, a session in web application for example is an implementation of a session storage to maintain its state somewhere, like on Redis Cache,  DB, and son on. If you want to maintain the session on SF, you have to implement a provider that stores the session information on reliable collections and the rest SF will handle the replication to the other nodes for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own asp.net core session state provider by implementing data protection and distributed cache interfaces:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository, ServiceFabricDataProtectionRepository>();
            services.AddDataProtection().AddKeyManagementOptions(options => options.XmlRepository = new ServiceFabricDataProtectionRepository());
            services.AddDistributedServiceFabricCache(o => { o.TableName = "test"; o.SessionService = new SessionService(); });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = ".ServiceFabric.Test.Session";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
        }
```

More here
https://github.com/sergeprivan/sf-sessionstateprovider